# Как зайти в recovery mode, если меню grub сразу же пропадает

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, sudo

Имеется проблема:

Файл `/etc/sudoers` имеет владельца и группу не `root:root`.
Из-за этого `sudo` не работает. Соответственно, и владельца не поменять.

Проблема решается заходом в *recovery mode → drop to root shell prompt* и сменой владельца и группы `/etc/sudoers`:

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers
```

Но дело в том, что не удаётся в меню *grub* выбрать *recovery mode*, т.к. меню пропадает слишком быстро.
Поменять опцию `GRUB_TIMEOUT` в файле `/etc/default/grub` не получится, т.к. для этого нужны права суперпользователя, а их нет.

Теоретически можно загрузиться с *liveCD*, но практически нельзя, так что этот вариант решения не рассматривается.

Каким образом в сложившейся ситуации можно зайти в *recovery mode*?

```
$ cat /proc/version    
Linux version 3.2.0-64-generic-pae (buildd@tipua) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 22:22:15 UTC 2014

$ grub-install -v
grub-install (GRUB) 1.99-12ubuntu5
```

Comment: если меню всё-таки появляется, нажмите что-нибудь вроде стрелки вниз (вверх) в момент его появления. счётчик времени должен остановиться.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо! Помогло следующее: одновременно зажать shift (для появления grub) и стрелку вниз ещё до появления меню.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если меню всё-таки появляется, нажмите что-нибудь вроде стрелки вниз (вверх) в момент его появления. счётчик времени должен остановиться.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё 1 вариант: часто-часто нажимать "Esc".

1. Включаем компьютер\ноутбук
2. Быстро нажимаем много раз "ESC".
3. Если производитель биоса не повесил на неё меню быстрой загрузки, то будет произведена загрузка с 1-го загрузочного устройства. Обычно с HDD.
4. GRUB при нажатии на Esc сбрасывает счётчик. Минимум это работает с ubuntu начиная с 10.04.